# Moving a VisualSVN repository to a remote UNC share

Tags: visualsvn-server

I’m attempting to move our repository to a network file share (using a UNC Path) but I am getting the following error when starting the server:

`Invalid file path //SERVERNAME/SVN/Repositories/authz-windows`

I can work around this error by manually editing httpd.conf and changing the “/” slashes to “\”. This is not ideal because httpd is regenerated whenever any settings starts, but it allows the server to start. However, then I get the following error when attempting to connect to the server:

`Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNAccessFile: Can't open file 'C:\\SERVERNAME\\SVN\\Repositories\\authz-windows': The system cannot find the path specified.

(OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.  [client 127.0.0.1]`

It appears that there are two issues here:

1. httpd.conf that VisualSVN Server generates contains the wrong slashes for a UNC path
2. The server is trying to look on C:\ instead of just using the UNC path.

I’m using VisualSVN Server 2.5.4.

Has anyone had any success placing their VisualSVN repositories on a remote UNC share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache HTTP Server uses forward slashes (`/`) in configuration files. You should not change them.

Did you read KB22(Storing repositories on a network share)?:
http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00022/

The `Invalid file path` error means that VisualSVN Server could not access Repositories folder or one of it's parent.

In case of network share you need to grant `Share` and `NTFS` access to the computer account where VisualSVN Server is running or configure service to run as dedicated domain account. See KB24 (Configuring VisualSVN Server service to run under a dedicated user account) for more details:
http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00024/

Comment: This worked - After discussing with the server admins, the Share permissions hadn't been updated, only the NTFS permissions were configured. Updating the Share permissions was all that was required. Thanks!